# Clase lista doble ordenada. Problema de ejecución (exit code 11)

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una clase para una lista doble ordenada, pero al ejecutarlo me da un exit code 11 (según lo que he leído es un problema de segmenatción, pero no puedo encontrar donde podría ser el problema)
al utilizar la función de abajo, alguien me pudiera decir si ve algún problema con la función? los atributos Primero y Ultimo son punteros al primer y ultimo elemento del elemento y valor es el valor guardado en cada estructura. Gracias.

```
template <typename T>
void ListaOrdenada<T>::AgregarElemento(const T &valor) {
    Elemento * aux = Primero;
    while(aux != NULL && aux ->valor < valor) aux = aux -> siguiente;
    Elemento * nuevo = new Elemento(valor, aux == NULL ? Ultimo : aux -> anterior, aux);
    (aux == Primero ? Primero : nuevo -> anterior ->siguiente) = nuevo;
    (aux != NULL ? aux -> anterior : Ultimo) = nuevo;
    ++numElem;
}
```

La estructura que estoy utilizando para el elemento es así:

```
 struct Elemento{
        T valor;
        Elemento * siguiente;
        Elemento * anterior;
        Elemento(T v,Elemento *ant = NULL ,Elemento *sig = NULL):valor(v), anterior(ant), siguiente(sig){}
    };
    Elemento * Primero;
    Elemento * Ultimo;
```

Comment: ¿Dónde da ell  errror?

Comment: Hola! No me arroja un error en sí, da un código de salida 11. Sí corre y sin marcar error, pero no ejecuta la función que puse ahí arriba.

Answer (score 1):

Ni idea de lo que es el código de salida 11, ya que los códigos de salida son dependientes de implementación (y no sabemos qué compilador usas ni bajo que sistema operativo trabajas) pero una rápida búsqueda en internet apunta a que puede ser una [violación de segmento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso), lo cuál tiene sentido por el uso extensivo de punteros y memoria dinámica en tu fragmento de código.

Apuesto a que el error está relacionado con el hecho de que no inicializas los punteros `Primero` ni `Ultimo`:

```
struct Elemento{
        T valor;
        Elemento * siguiente;
        Elemento * anterior;
        Elemento(T v,Elemento *ant = NULL ,Elemento *sig = NULL):
            valor(v), anterior(ant), siguiente(sig){}
    };
    Elemento * Primero; // Sin inicializar!!
    Elemento * Ultimo;  // Sin inicializar!!
```

Esto provocará un error de acceso en el primer bucle al igualar `aux` a `Primero`, siendo este diferente de `NULL` intentará seguir la dirección no válida para acceder a `valor` provocando el fallo:

```
// 'Primero' no se sabe donde apunta
Elemento * aux = Primero;

while(aux != NULL && aux ->valor < valor) aux = aux -> siguiente;
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~~~
//         \              \_________ No se puede seguir la direccion 'aux': violacion de segmento
//          \
//           \__________ 'aux' no es null porque 'Primero' no lo es.
```

También puede suceder una violación de segmento en esta línea:

```
(aux == Primero ? Primero : nuevo -> anterior ->siguiente) = nuevo;
```

Cuando `nuevo -> anterior` sea `NULL`, no se podrá seguir dicha dirección y fallará.